# Meaning of "renaissance loser"

Tags: meaning

*Renaissance loser* in this [context](http://www.dilbert.com/strips/comic/2000-12-22/)

> Dilbert: Wally, are you free for lunch? I need to remind myself how lucky I am that I don't have your laziness or personality or looks.
>
> Wally: Would you say I'm kind of a renaissance loser?

Does it describe people who have multiple attributes of a loser? So can renaissance be used to address things with multiple attributes like people who know art and science?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, your explanation is along the right lines.

*Renaissance loser* is a play on the phrase [*renaissance man*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/renaissance+man), which is someone who is thought to be an expert in many fields. This is similar to the word [polymath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymath).

So Wally is suggesting that he has become the epitome of a loser in many fields. This could, in fact, be seen as the antonym of *renaissance man*.

Comment: A singificant proportion of [Google's 91 results for 'Renaissance loser'](http://www.google.co.uk/#q=%22Renaissance+loser%22&hl=en&newwindow=1&prmd=imvnsb&ei=V7PHTsfaPIeq8AON_uyMAQ&start=90&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=dd5d8acaa378c290&biw=1137&bih=830) reference OP's Dilbert cartoon, so it's hardly a standard expression. I realise using "loser" this way has become common, but I still think it's a "low-brow" alternative to **Renaissance Man manque**.

Comment: @FumbleFingers — I didn't mean to imply that *renaissance loser* is a common expression, or an idiom. This is the first time I have heard it.

Comment: Nor did I intend any criticism of what you wrote, which all seems perfectly correct to me. I was just pointing out that I think to a considerable extent "loser" here is being used the way many of us have long been using "manque". And explicitly making the point that "Renaissance loser" is not really a "set phrase".